# Focus on the first empty textBox in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

I am trying to focus on the first empty `TextBox` item.

How can I focus on the first empty `TextBox`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding which textbox is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815415/finding-which-textbox-is-empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `foreach` loop to iterate through all `TextBox`es in your Form.
Example:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text)) {
        tb.Focus();
        break;
    }
}
```